# Why do I get an error signing ionic-cordova ios app from the command line if it works perfectly in the gui version of xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an Ionic - Cordova iOs app from the command line (to use an azure devops build and deployment agent), but from the last updates (certificates, xcode, OS, etc), i have no success anymore.

After trying a lot of options, i'm some lost with xcode command line. A 'few updates' before, this command where working perfectly, so I don't know what are happening with the profiles and certificates.

This is the command lines that I'm using:

```
 security unlock-keychain -p **** [keychainpath] 

 ionic build --prod

 ionic cordova build ios --no-build --release --device --provisioningProfile="*****" -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" --developmentTeam=***** --codeSignIdentity="iPhone Developer" --packageType=app-store
```

And this this is the result (I omitting all the log before the "archive succeded"):

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

2019-11-15 08:01:36.413 xcodebuild[32327:470732] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/jg/06xlqgms5n54qgh0mcj3tkvw0000gp/T/******_2019-11-15_08-01-36.412.xcdistributionlogs'.
error: exportArchive: No profiles for '*********' were found

Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for '*****' were found" UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for '******' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching '******'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

(node:31915) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,*******.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/*****/*****/_work/1/s/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/*****/*****/_work/1/s/platforms/ios/build/device
(node:31915) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31915) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tryied to build the app with the GUI of XCode (and the same user) without problems, so I guess that certificates and provisioning profiles there must be allright.

Any clue on what are happening with the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer: It was a bad combination of distribution profile and development profile parameters.

I found it using the --verbose mode in cordova build

I changed the way to define the parameters to build the ios package using a "build.json" definition file:

**build.json**

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "*******",
            "packageType: development,
            "provisioningProfile": "*******"
        },
         "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
            "developmentTeam": "******",
            "packageType": "app-store",
            "provisioningProfile": "*******"
        }
    }
}
```

Which can used with the command line as follows:

```
ionic cordova build ios --no-build --prod --release --device --buildConfig build.json
```

Thanks to this I was able to see where the problem was and finally a was able to get the ipa file well signed.

Comment: Can you provide your build definition on azure pipeline ?  I'm struggling with errors.  Thanks to your suggestion I was able to fix one issue.  My current error on azure CD is : error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "*******" with a private key was found. (in target 'myApp' from project 'myApp')